# Vaadin binder. can't save data to the database

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin

i am trying to save an object obtained from a TextField to the database but i get null

```
public void save(TextField name) {
        book = new Book();
        Binder<Book> binder= new Binder<>(Book.class);
        binder.bindInstanceFields(book);
        binder.forField(name).bind(Book::getName, Book::setName);
        bookService.save(book);
    }
```

Comment: You lack the `setBean` or `writeBean`

Comment: You may have a mistaken idea of how bindInstanceFields is supposed to work. Check the JavaDoc.

Comment: could you give me a simple example of how to get data from textfield with binder please?

Comment: You put binder into use when you set up the form, not when the save button is pressed. https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder.html

Answer (score 2):

I have rearranged your code a little. It should work like this:

```
 @Route(value = BinderStackOverflowView.ROUTE, layout = MainLayout.class)
 public class BinderStackOverflowView extends VerticalLayout {

     public static final String ROUTE = "BinderStackOverflowView";
     public static final String TITLE = "BinderStackOverflowView";

     private final static Logger LOGGER = 
                          Logger.getLogger(BinderStackOverflowView.class.getName());

     private Book book;

     public BinderStackOverflowView()  {

         TextField textField = new TextField("name");

         Button saveButton = new Button("Save");

         book = new Book();
         
         Binder<Book> binder = new Binder<>(Book.class);
         binder.forField(textField).bind(Book::getName, Book::setName);
         binder.setBean(book);

         saveButton.addClickListener(event -> save(book));
         add(textField, saveButton);
     }

     public void save(Book book) {
         LOGGER.info("book: " + book.getName());
         // bookService.save(book);
     }

 }
```

Crucial, as cfrick mentioned, is also binder.setBean(myBean)